# Conversion of lat and lon into geo point data type in ELK 6.3 version on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: elasticsearch, search, logstash, kibana

We are trying to push the data into elasticsearch using .conf file and .json (template file) in the ELK version 6.3. Initially we pushed the data into ELK 4.x version successfully using template file and were able to render the points on the map. But in the new version, with/without using template file, lat and lon are only being seen as a number in Kibana.

How do we push lat,lon so that it has geopoint type? We are trying to push data using logstash configuration file.

Here's our .conf file:

```
[input
{
    file
        {
        path => "/home/ubuntu/file.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => \[
          "CASCADE",
          "Accessibility",
          "Sustainability",
          "CONNECTION_FAIL_per",
          "RRC_CONNECTION_ATTEMPT",     
               "eCSFB_to_CDMA1XRTT_Exe_Succ_Count",
          "eCSFB_Preparation_Success_Rate",
          "eCSFB_Overall_Success_Rate",
          "CSFB_Attempts",
        "Total_PUCCH_PRB_UL_per",
          "lat",
          "lon"


        \]
    }

    mutate { convert => {"lat" => "float"} }
    mutate { convert => {"lon" => "float"} }
    mutate { rename => {"lat" => "\[location\]\[lat\]"} }
    mutate { rename => {"lon" => "\[location\]\[lon\]"} }

}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        template => "/usr/share/elasticsearch/new.json"
        template_overwrite => true
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "new"
        workers => 1
    }
    stdout {}
}                                                                                       

template file : new.json

{
  "template" : "new",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
      "dynamic_templates" : \[ {
        "message_field" : {
          "match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
            }
          }
        }
      } \],
     "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
        "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
            "lat" : { "type" : "float" },
            "lon" : { "type" : "float" }
          }
        },
  "location" : { "type": "geo_point" }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Please let us know how to convert into Geo-point

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: We are getting lat,lon in number type but we want in geopoint type. We are trying to push data using logstash configuration file. Version of ELK is 6.3